# Register an App ID

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-id

I'm trying to publish my first app on the AppStore. In order to do that I am trying to add an iOS App ID to my identifiers. My issue is that I always get the following error message:

> There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
>
> An App ID with Identifier 'com.myTeam.myApp' is not available. Please
>   enter a different string.

I verified if the App IDmatched my bundle ID in Xcode and it's the case.

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this warning may mean that the bundle ID you trying to submit is already secured by someone else. bundle ID is global for entire AppStore.
Try to use different bundle ID and if it's OK with it, just specify it in  your project settings.

Comment: So I can set an App ID in iTunesConnect and if it is accepted change to the same afterwards in my Xcode project ?

Comment: yes, but you make AppID not in iTunesConnect, but on developer.apple.com